# SQL query with count and case statement

Tags: sql, count, case

i need to find how many people have filed (fil_dt) their tax return within 60 days, withing 120 days, within 180 days, over 180 days of their filing period end date (fpe) for 3 different years (2006, 2007, 2008)

the statement below will give me ALL years
i need a count for each year and for each possibility..
anyway i can do this without 2 queries ?

```
SELECT YEAR(A.FPE) AS "YEAR"
,CASE                                              
  WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 60 THEN '2 ' 
  WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 120 THEN '4 '
  WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 180 THEN '6 '
  WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) > 180 THEN '6+'
 END AS "NBR MTH"                                  
WHERE A.FPE BETWEEN '2006-01-01' AND '2008-12-31'
```

i need your help
thanks a lot

Answer (score 22, accepted):

then write

```
   SELECT YEAR(A.FPE) AS "YEAR",
       Sum(CASE WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 60 
                  THEN 1 Else 0 End) SixtydayCount,  
       Sum(CASE WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 120 
                  THEN 1 Else 0 End) OneTwentyDayCount,
       Sum(CASE WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 180 
                  THEN 1  Else 0 End) OneEightyDayCount,
       Sum(CASE WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) > 180 
                  THEN 1 Else 0 End)  OverOneEightyCount  
    From Table A
    WHERE A.FPE BETWEEN '2006-01-01' AND '2008-12-31'
    Group By YEAR(A.FPE)
```

If you want the 120 day count and the 180 day count to only include the folks who are over 60 and less than 120, etc. then,

```
     SELECT YEAR(A.FPE) AS "YEAR",
       Sum(CASE WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 60 
                  THEN 1 Else 0 End) SixtydayCount,  
       Sum(CASE WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) Between 60 And 119 
                  THEN 1 Else 0 End) OneTwentyDayCount,
       Sum(CASE WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) Between 120 And 179 
                  THEN 1  Else 0 End) OneEightyDayCount,
       Sum(CASE WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) >= 180 
                  THEN 1 Else 0 End)  OverOneEightyCount  
    From Table A
    WHERE A.FPE BETWEEN '2006-01-01' AND '2008-12-31'
    Group By YEAR(A.FPE)
```

Comment: The sums will add up to more than `100%`: `< 60` implies `< 120` and further. I think the `@op` meant something like `from 0 to 60`, `from 61 to 120` and so on.

Comment: @Quassnoi,  Yes, Added second query to show how to do exclusive counts... But How did you highlight text in a comment ? Please tell...

Comment: `@Charles Bretana`: just like you do it in the posts, enclosing the text into backticks and asterisks.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  CASE
        WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 60 THEN '2 ' 
        WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 120 THEN '4 '
        WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 180 THEN '6 '
        WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) > 180 THEN '6+'
        END AS NBR_MTH,
        y,
        COUNT(a.fpe)
FROM    (
        SELECT  2006 AS y
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2007 AS y
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2008 AS y
        )
LEFT JOIN
        A
ON      A.FPE >= CAST(CONCAT(y, '-01-01') AS DATETIME)
        AND a.FPE < CAST(CONCAT(y + 1, '-01-01') AS DATETIME)
GROUP BY
        y, mbr_mth
```

Unlike the simple `GROUP BY YEAR()`, this will select `0` even for the missing records (like, if there were no `6+` records in `2008`)

Answer (score 2):

Group by the column your case statement represents:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(A.FPE) AS "YEAR",
  CASE                                              
    WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 60 THEN '2 ' 
    WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 120 THEN '4 '
    WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 180 THEN '6 '
    WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) > 180 THEN '6+'
  END AS "NBR MTH",
  COUNT(1) AS "TOTAL"
FROM Table
WHERE 
  A.FPE BETWEEN '2006-01-01' AND '2008-12-31'
GROUP BY
  "YEAR",
  "NBR MTH"
```

This query will give you a count of every record for each unique year/"NBR MTH" combination.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, most DBMSs don't allow GROUP BY using aliases, so it must be

```
...
GROUP BY 
  YEAR(A.FPE),
  CASE                                              
    WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 60 THEN '2 ' 
    WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 120 THEN '4 '
    WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) < 180 THEN '6 '
    WHEN DAYS(A.FIL_DT) - DAYS(A.FPE) > 180 THEN '6+'
  END
```